# LDAP - error: 'Cannot send the simple bind request: SSLException(Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?)'

Tags: oracle, ldap, directoryservices

I'm trying to export data using export-ldif command of Oracle Unified Directory. but getting below error.

Command entered in cmd
export-ldif --hostname  --port  --bindDN  "cn=Directory Manager" -w password --includeBranch "ou=xyz,ou=abc" --backendID userRoot --ldifFile c:\example16jan.ldif

Error
You have provided options for scheduling this operation as a task but options
provided for connecting to the server's tasks backend resulted in the
following error: 'Cannot send the simple bind request:
SSLException(Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?)'

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E22289_01/html/821-1279/export-ldif.html

Answer (score 1):

I guess the message is explicit... 
The port number (normally specified with --port XXXX, but you've omited the port number in the command above), is a plain LDAP port. 
The export-ldif tool, being an administrative tool, expects to connect to a secure port (either 636 or the Administration port 4444).